# Icon arrow positions in collapsing tables - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have an issue with the font-icons and collapsing tabs in Twitter Bootstrap.

My goal is to visualize the **icon arrow down** as default and not **up** and i dont want to see the first collapsing tab open as default.

Then when i click over the **icon arrow down** the icon has to toggle swtitch.

I think i am really close to it, look the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/2D3V5/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So getting the accordion to load with all the tabs closed can be achieved by:

```
$('.collapse').collapse("hide");
```

Then you just need to change the class of the icons:

```
<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
```

Then you should have the arrows point down as default and up when the tab is opened.

There seems to be something weird going on in the JS fiddle with the collapse, sometimes when you open and close tabs the text is not hiding properly, I tried this on a normal page and it seems to work okay.

Comment: Hi DaveR , you are right, in Jsfiddle doesn t work as it should, i have made these changes on my project and it's ok. Thanks for your useful answer